# What does [] mean after function in python syntax

Tags: python, syntax

What mean in python when i'm after function set `[::-1]` or `[:64]` for example? Here is code example

```
var = binascii.unhexlify(data)[:64]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation

Comment: Or you could just read the [Informal Introduction](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) chapter that kicks off the tutorial, which covers slices half-way down the page. And presumably any other source for learning Python (short of just hacking at code you don't understand and then asking random strangers to explain things to you when it doesn't seem to work) will cover it about as early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`binascii.unhexlify` returns a string. The brackets are applied to that object, not the function. It is just a short version of

```
x = binascii.unhexlify(data)
var = x[:64]
```

Comment: What if i set [::-1], what this mean?